# ACL rule for website access

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Good evening,

I currently have deployed a VPN in azure, in this network I have added a cloud service and have also granted access to an azure website, so far so good.

Now I want the cloud service to be available only to the nodes of my VPN, especially the azure website. In order to achieve this I have created some ACLs which grant access to every node of my subnet i.e,

```
<Rule action="permit" description="test2" order="200" remoteSubnet="172.16.0.0/27" />
```

However, once the ACL Rule is enforced, the website has no access to the cloud service and therefor a timeout exception is thrown. **Am I doing something wrong or the only way to achieve this is to deploy both of my projects on cloud services instead of a website and a cloud service?** It is vital for this project that the cloud service is only available locally.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently restrict Azure Websites to only be accessible via a private VNet and as you suggested you will need to use either Web Role (Cloud Service) or a VM.

Comment: Simon, I do not want to restrict the access to the Azure websites what I want is the Azure Websites to be able to access the cloud service which will be only accesible via a private VNet. Is it possible?

Comment: @oskar132 once you have connected your Azure Website to your VNet you would need to understand the origin IP of the Website traffic - how you do that will depend on what you're connecting to (a DB, an API, etc). That's the IP (or range) that you'd include in your definition or in an Network Security Group (NSG).